# Sort HTML emlements by child contents

Tags: html, sorting, text, children

I have these elements in a list. I want to sort the list alphabetically but how do i do that if the text that i want to sort it by is in a child element?

```
<div class="entry">
<button class="title btn btn-primary">Tale of Memories</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post some relevant code.

Comment: You could put the name as a data attribute in the div then follow http://jsfiddle.net/MikeGrace/Vgavb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it is difficult to know exactly how things will work. Here is a generic solution:

1. Select all the elements in the list (eg: using `querySelectorAll`).
2. Transform the result of step 1 into an array (eg: with [this solution from andrewmu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4761219/3695983))
3. Use the native [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method to sort the array (providing your own function to compare values based on whatever you want).
4. Rewrite the content of the list with the content of the array.

Here is a demo. In it, we sort the list not based on the text directly in each item, but on the text from the `span` within each of them (for that reason the FA item goes first instead of last). In your case, you will want to change the compare function to get whichever element you want the items to be compared by:

```js
// step 1: select the list items
var items = document.querySelectorAll("#mylist li");

// step 2: convert the node list into an array
var itemsarray = Array.prototype.slice.call(items, 0)

// step 3: sort the array using your own compare function
itemsarray.sort(function(a,b) {
 return a.querySelector("span").innerHTML > b.querySelector("span").innerHTML;
});

// step 4: empty the list, and insert the sorted items
var ml = document.getElementById("mylist");
ml.innerHTML = "";
for (var x = 0; x < itemsarray.length; x++) {
 ml.appendChild(itemsarray[x]);
}
```

```html
<ul id="mylist">
  <li><span>E</span></li>
  <li><span>D</span></li>
  <li><span>B</span></li>
  <li>F<span>A</span></li>
  <li><span>C</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed.